# AJAX FIle Upload: Filename doesn't appear in textfield of type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making use of [Andrew Valums](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) awesome AJAX file uploader.

I am having a problem with it though, its a small issue. I want the file that was selected by the user and uploaded to be shown in the textfield. But it never seems to appear it just uploads.

How can I do this or why is this happening?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by doing something different. Using a text field and button to simulate an input of type file and it works a treat.